# Creating a loop?

Tags: python, loops, tweepy

I'm a bit of a novice a python but was wondering how to create a loop so that the code below could be run over multiple twitter ids instead of just the '433016508592037888'?

I have so far:

```
import tweepy


consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_key = ""
access_secret = "" 


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def get_retweet_count(tweet_id):
    tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id)
    return tweet.retweet_count

print get_retweet_count( '433016508592037888')
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had the id's in a list:

ex:  `id_list = [id, id, id, id, id]` `# imagine those are id numbers :)`

then you could do something like:

```
for id in id_list:
    print get_retweet_count(id)
```

for info on for loops and python loops in general, click [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm) and [here(codeacademy, python tutorials)](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-cxMGf/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096) and google ;)